# Get the number of downloads/views in SP online document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, auditing

I want to get a report for a duration where I need below details for all the files in a document library. Any suggestions on OOB or PowerShell or any other way?

1. Date & Time
2. User details

Answer (score 0):

Please go to Microsoft 365 admin center>Compliance>Audit to get results and export it as a report:

[image]

More information about audit search for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance?view=o365-worldwide#step-1-run-an-audit-log-search

Comment: Thanks, let me check and confirm